# Изменить расположение осей на на совмещенных графиках MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Добавляю несколько графиков на один subplot с помощью функции twiny(). Необходимо чтобы оси этих функций находились друг над  другом над графиком. Но получается, что в нужное место встает только последняя добавленная.
Вот пример кода:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 9))


a = [6.894, 6.793, 6.652, 6.938, 7.331, 7.436, 7.342, 7.412, 7.702, 7.911, 7.962, 7.948, 8.244, 8.512, 8.511, 8.192,
     7.973, 8.093, 8.238, 8.212, 7.976, 7.806, 7.821, 7.971, 7.94, 7.762]
b = [108.554, 113.713, 116.631, 116.761, 120.038, 130.367, 149.388, 182.786, 222.443, 247.135, 268.323, 267.853,
     269.966, 281.659, 288.23, 324.852, 405.057, 491.367, 635.459, 785.158, 863.303, 870.333, 711.333, 554.96, 445.188,
     373.541]
c = [1.11, 1.084, 0.989, 0.882, 0.879, 0.994, 1.285, 1.386, 1.336, 1.059, 0.968, 0.968, 0.993, 0.872, 0.874, 0.865,
     0.966, 1.088, 1.187, 1.238, 1.037, 0.909, 0.866, 0.965, 0.97, 0.995,]

for i in range(3):

     ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, i+1)

     ax.plot(a, range(len(a)), c='r')
     ax.set_xlabel('a', color='r')
     ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
     ax.axes.xaxis.tick_top()
     ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='r')
     ax.axes.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
     ax.spines.top.set_position(("axes", 1.00))
     ax.invert_yaxis()

     ax = ax.twiny()
     ax.plot(b, range(len(a)), c='b')
     ax.set_xlabel('b', color='b')
     ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
     ax.axes.xaxis.tick_top()
     ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='b')
     ax.axes.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
     ax.spines.top.set_position(("axes", 1.03))
     ax.invert_yaxis()

     ax = ax.twiny()
     ax.plot(c, range(len(a)), c='g')
     ax.set_xlabel('c', color='g')
     ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
     ax.axes.xaxis.tick_top()
     ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='g')
     ax.axes.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
     ax.spines.top.set_position(("axes", 1.06))
     ax.invert_yaxis()


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно аккуратнее работать с регионами (axes), особенно, если вы разделяете между ними одну из осей. советую каждый график выводить отдельным регионом, иначе последний график просто перезаписывает все своими данными. Обратите внимание, что для первого графика тоже обязательно объявить `ax.twiny()`:

```
for i in range(3):

     ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, i+1)
    
     ax_0 = ax.twiny()

     ax_0.plot(a, range(len(a)), c='r')
     ax_0.set_xlabel('a', color='r')
     ax_0.axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
     ax_0.axes.xaxis.tick_top()
     ax_0.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='r')
     ax_0.axes.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
     ax_0.spines.top.set_position(("axes", 1.00))
     ax_0.invert_yaxis()

     ax_1 = ax.twiny()
     ax_1.plot(b, range(len(a)), c='b')
     ax_1.set_xlabel('b', color='b')
     ax_1.axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
     ax_1.axes.xaxis.tick_top()
     ax_1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='b')
     ax_1.axes.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
     ax_1.spines.top.set_position(("axes", 1.06))
     ax_1.invert_yaxis()

     ax_2 = ax.twiny()
     ax_2.plot(c, range(len(a)), c='g')
     ax_2.set_xlabel('c', color='g')
     ax_2.axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
     ax_2.axes.xaxis.tick_top()
     ax_2.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='g')
     ax_2.axes.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
     ax_2.spines.top.set_position(("axes", 1.12))
     ax_2.invert_yaxis()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а вообще, советую почитать про [Secondary Axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html)

Comment: Тут вообще явно можно сделать цикл и не копипастить большой блок кода с большой вероятностью ошибки )

Comment: Cамо собой в рабочем коде не так, просто для примера накидал.